# Qt Creator Ide, problem building after adding instance of QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt

Please can someone give me an indication.  When I see an error like this in visual studio, I usually know I'm missing a lib.  However I'm using qt right out the box so to speak through its own ide.  I do not know why QTcpSocket won't build.

> mainwindow.obj:: error:  unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual _*thiscall
>   QTcpSocket::~QTcpSocket(void)" (*_imp_??1QTcpSocket@@UAE@XZ)
>   referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall
>   MainWindow::~MainWindow(void)" (??1MainWindow@@UAE@XZ)
>
> mainwindow.obj:: error:  unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QTcpSocket::QTcpSocket(class
>   QObject *)" (_*imp*??0QTcpSocket@@QAE@PAVQObject@@@Z) referenced in
>   function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)"
>   (??0MainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtNetwork/QHostAddress>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QTcpSocket sckSock;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Are your constructor and destructor actually implemented somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your .pro file, you should add something like:

```
QT += network
```

So the correct libs get linked. See [QtNetwork Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtnetwork.html) for more information.